# .htaccess causes fail in parsing source maps

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess, centos, source-maps

On the web page the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off

# skip POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]

Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /img/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /img/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /img/500.png
```

It causes the next error:

```
Failed to parse SourceMap: .../js/bootstrap-select.js.map
```

When I delete it, the error doesn't occur.
How should I modify .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing **error.php** to a picture ( in error.php there was redirect to index page ).

Comment: Hello mate , always use image for error redirection or for htaccess hot-linking redirection on error else it might cause indefinite loop. Anyways glad that you found the solution .

Answer (score 3):

Even though you had answered yourself just i want to post this so that others with this issue will know exactly what that happens

**Warning:**

> Do not use .htaccess to redirect error to another HTML/PHP  page or server
>   that isn't your own (such as this error.php). Errors can be replaced
>   by other images, not with an HTML or PHP page as that might cause indefinite
>   loop too.